# How to validate JSON object before feeding to SQLAlchemy object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

When I want to create or update an object in my database, I send JSON from the client. I use SQLAlchemy to operate data. A model already has all the needed information about types like:

```
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'project'
    creation_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(Project, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

So, I want to be able to feed a raw JSON into the constructor and check if all the fields fit the types. I can do it with Marshmallow but I found I must recreate the schema like that:

```
class ProjectSchema(db_schema.Schema):
    title = fields.Str(required=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('date', 'event', 'comment')
```

what is very annoying and not safe because all the information about fields should be duplicated. Is there any way to do it automatically based on one source?

Comment: What do you mean by "fit the types"? Do you want to actually type check, or just know whether all the fields are present? Do you want to deal with nullable values, or just ignore it whenever a column is missing from the JSON?

Comment: Actually, both. If nullable == False it should not be None, and if it's db.String it should be String, not something else. I found SQLAlchemy makes casting on its own but in some cases the primary validation would be helpful like if the type is date and coming value is string and it can't be casted to date for some reason.

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this @mimic?

Comment: @kevthanewversi Honestly, I don't remember as I faced this problem more than 2 years ago. But I suppose I just found some workaround because I usually add the updates if I find the solution. I can't tell you for sure, sorry.